# retain formatting from source document in mail-merge

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge, text-formatting

I have set up a mail-marge in Word 2003. The source is a document where each field is a formatted text as the following one:

I have **different** *pieces of text* to insert.

However, when I insert such a Merge Field in my primary document, it losts its original formatting. Is it possible to retain all the formatting I have set in the source document file?

Comment: Could you clarify, are you having problems getting the mergefield to use the same formatting as surrounding content, or when you merge the field with data you having trouble getting the formatting of that to stay the same?

Comment: The latter you said. I want the text to appear in the merged document as I have formatted in the source document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "REF" instead of "MERGEFIELD".  It's a little strange, but I found it to preserve formatting with superscripts, and bolded characters.

https://superuser.com/a/457222/143655

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the "Preserve formatting during updates" checkbox ticked in the dialog which is shown when creating the merge field. You can display this dialog for an existing field by right clicking on it and choosing "Edit Field".

This option will include the "MERGEFORMAT" switch which will instruct the mail merge engine to keep the formatting that is initially applied to the field when it's merged with data.

Comment: Sorry, I've checked the box you have suggested but still my text does not retain original formatting. Here is as the source document and the mailmerge document appear: http://i.imgur.com/rzOii.png

Comment: @Toc, thanks. can you also attach the template somewhere as well?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/T5Tdc.png is this what you are asking for or not?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me!
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/320473/excel-data-does-not-retain-its-formatting-in-mail-merge-operations-in

In addition, I'll share a small trick that helped me - ensure that the Mail Merge tab (containing the mail merge info) is the first tab in the Excel file.

Hope this helps others having the same issue.

Comment: Consider providing the content from the link that helped you resolve in case the link goes bad the content is still quoted on this post.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.